# Google Places Find_Place API request does not return business name

Tags: python, google-places-api

This Python script does not return the business name when the business address is specified.  I would expect the business name "Popeye's" to be returned. Why is it not returning the business name?  Is there an issue with the "fields= ['name']" parameter?

```
import googlemaps
import pprint
import time
import os

API_KEY = os.getenv('API_KEY')

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key = API_KEY)

name_result = gmaps.find_place(input=”5949 NE Martin Luther King Jr Blvd, Portland, OR 97211”, input_type= “textquery”, fields= ['name'])
pprint.pprint(name_result)
{'candidates': [{'name': '5949 NE Martin Luther King Jr Blvd'}], 'status': 'OK'}
```